# How to find size of RediSearch Index

Tags: redis, redis-search

I found Redis Search [calculator](https://redis.com/modules/redis-search/redisearch-sizing-calculator/) that can estimate index size but how I can find out that by Redis commands?

I tried to do that using **FT.INFO** but I am even not close to the value from the calculator.

What i did:

1. I multiplied **bytes_per_record_avg** * **num_records**
2. After that I sum those vars: **doc_table_size_mb** + **key_table_size_mb** + **sortable_values_tize_mb** + **inwerted_size_mb** + **offset_vector_sz_mb**

I sum value from **point 1** with value from **point 2** and I received around **120mb** BUT based on calculator(and also based on real ram usage I believe) it should be around **400mb**

How I can get closer to the right value?